# Website versioning scheme enabling periodical add-feature/remove-feature changes

Tags: git

Forgive me if this question sound silly or obvious, but I would rather ask and do things the correct/preferred way and learn something along the way...

I manage a live production website for a client of mine, which is currently tagged in Git as version 1.4.0.

Every year, for the past 2 years, he has donated his home page to a charity for a day, whereby they provide him (and he subsequently forwards me) a snippet of code to add into the markup for a popup to display on the homepage.

The core functionality of the site has not changed; the only thing that has is the adding/removing of the snippet, so every year I bump the version number for adding the snippet and then bump it again removing the snippet.

So, the website started at version 1.0.0 when it was released; was bumped to 1.1.0 when the code was added; then bumped to 1.2.0 when the code was removed; then to 1.3.0 when it was added for the 2nd year; and then to 1.4.0 when it was removed again.

So basically, version 1.0.0, 1.2.0, and 1.4.0, have the exact same code.

Would this mean that I would have to continue creating a new release and bumping the version number every time they provide this snippet of code and then its removal, or is there some better way of handling this?

Edit: Just to add, the snippet provided by the charity is the same every year and does not change.

Comment: This will lead to opinionated answers. In my opinion in an x.y.z versioning scheme for a regular website: a X version introduces major changes like a new design or new URLs that break search engine indexes. A Y version introduces (non-breaking) new features, like adding a new page or swapping out images. A Z version is for minor tweaks like bugfixes or this sort of popup tweaks. So yes, I'd increment the version for each new snippet -- but I would increment the Z version instead of Y.

Comment: Plenty of information published about versioning (major/minor/patch, for instance), but really...  no right answer to this. Up to you to decide. On Stackoverflow, this type of question is off-topic as it will only lead to opinions and debate.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. @DavidMakogon In your opinion, may I ask what would you do?

Comment: In my opinion, you're doing it simply wrong. And I don't mean versioning, but the thing you do. Why do you update/replace/remove this snippet all the time? Add it permanently, wrap with some condition and add a **configuration setting** that will turn it on/off. The code will stay one and the same from now on, and only the setting will be turned on/off by configuration when you/him wants it to. If you need to customize the code snippet, because, for example, every year some crypto-hash or bank-number changes, move that part to configuration as well and it's done.

Comment: My opinion doesn't really matter here, as I wouldn't have implemented a popup toggle via changing code back and forth every year. Also, even if I *did* take the same approach, I wouldn't have seen the enabling or disabling of a popup as a "minor" change in the `major.minor.patch` versioning scheme. Think about your versioning approach, and what it means to folks when version `1.0.0` is identical to `1.2.0` and `1.4.0`...

Comment: I thank you all for your opinions, it has given me new insight. I now believe it would be best to build the functionality into the site to enable/disable the popup whenever needed, and therefore the answer provided by @quetzalcoatl would be the best way to approach this for me in this instance, and the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you're doing it simply wrong. And I don't mean versioning, but the thing you actually do: changing the code back-and-forth.

Why do you update/replace/remove this snippet all the time? I know it's easy to copy-paste-select-delete, but you just make it harder for you to manage the website. If it is noticeably repetitive, make it into a feature.

Add that snippet permanently, wrap with some condition and add a **configuration setting** that will turn it on/off (surely you have some configuration already, jsut use it). The code will stay one and the same from now on, and only that setting will be turned on/off by configuration when you/him wants it to.

If you need to customize the code snippet, because, for example, every year some crypto-hash or bank-number changes, move that part to configuration as well and it's done.